# Footer height doesn't fill screen?

Tags: html, css

I've been testing my site on multiple devices, and when testing on a screen with high resolution there is all this extra white space underneath the footer.

[image]

How do I make the height dynamic, fixing this issue?

My HTML is as follows:

```
    <div class="contact">
        <div class="content--container">
          ........
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="columns is-multiline">
                <div class="column is-12">
                  .......
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      ......
    </div>
```

Comment: I am sure there are dozens of answers for this question on SO

Comment: Do you want it fixed always at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add these for CSS (it's from http://mystrd.at/modern-clean-css-sticky-footer/):

```
html {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0 0 100px; /* bottom = footer height */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML template for that is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <article>Lorem ipsum...</article>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Next option is to use flexbox like these example: https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/sticky-footer/

In these example body has `class="Site"` and content also have a class called `class="Site-content"` and looks like these:

```
<body class="Site">
  <header>Your header</header>
  <main class="Site-content">
     <div> Text </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

CSS for these example looks like:

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Full source for the Site component used in this example you can find here: https://github.com/philipwalton/solved-by-flexbox/blob/master/assets/css/components/site.css

Comment: How is this an answer? What about future visitors, after these links are potentially broken?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I add some examples from that links. I think it's 
more readable now.

Comment: Looks better. Please avoid using external links in your answers, because they can easily get deleted over time, which would make your answer unusable in the future.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy fix would be to add a min-height to your .contact element.

Assuming it sits directly insider your body element, and if your footer height is 200px, you could do:

```
.contact {
   min-height: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

This does require that your body is either position:static; (the default) or has a min-height of 100%.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a min-height to your body like this:

   ```
   body {
       min-height: 100%;
   }
   ```
2. Change your footer `position` to `absolute` like this:

   ```
   .footer {
       position: absolute;
   }
   ```
3. Position and add width to your footer like this:

   ```
   .footer {
       position: absolute;
       bottom:0;
       left:0;
       width: 100%;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to make a footer look like it has a dynamic height (if a tall footer height doesn't matter to you) is by changing the body's background-color to match the footer's. Then you can give one of your containers a 100% width and apply a different background-color.

That gives you the visual separation of the content and the footer without having to position or resize the footer.

Heres's the CSS:

```
  body {
    background-color: tomato;
    height: 100%;
  }

  header { 
    color: white; 
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .container {
    background-color: white;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  footer {
    background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
  }
```

and the HTML:

```
<header>
    <h1>This is my header</h1>
</header>
<div class="container">
    <p>This is my content</p>
</div>
<footer> 
    <p> this is my footer that looks like it has a variable height.</p>
</footer>
```

Link to a working example:
http://codepen.io/Brydave/pen/dNQJMb